# My webpack doesn't generate my css file

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an issue with webpack and my react app. I am developing my app in react, but when I run my bundle script to run webpack, it doesn't generate the output css.

Here is my component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

import styles from './Header.css'

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <h1>
        Mi first react app
      </h1>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <Link to="/">
          Home
        </Link>
        <a 
          href="http://google.com"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Google
        </a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

My webpack config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../src/client.js')],
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../built/statics')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2016', 'es2017', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?modules' })
      }
    ]
  },
  target: 'web',
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../statics/styles.css')
  ],
  watch: true
}
```

If you need, my css is this:

```
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1c3643 0, #273b46 25%, #1e5372);
}
```

In advance, thanks for any help to discover what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try making changes as mentioned below?

What is "Header.css" ?

What is the use of this code?

```
import styles from './Header.css'
```

The filename is *styles.css* as mentioned in *ExtractTextPlugin*.

You should directly include "statics/styles.css" file in your HTML.

Also, here

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <h1>
        Mi first react app
      </h1>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <Link to="/">
          Home
        </Link>
        <a 
          href="http://google.com"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Google
        </a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

The goal of ExtractTextplugin is to generate a separate single CSS file which could be used separately as in general case.